# DB2 - Unable to connect sqlcode: -1598,

Tags: javascript, node.js, db2, odbc

I'm using `ibm_db` library in my electron app. I need to connect to an instance of db2 that is running on our AS400 system. I'm doing the connection using this code after that the electron application is started

```js
        const connStr = "DATABASE=mydb01;HOSTNAME=192.168.0.15;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx;PORT=446;PROTOCOL=TCPIP";

        const ibmdb = new Database()
        ibmdb.open( connStr, (err, conn) => {
            console.log(err, conn)
        })
```

The problem is that it will ask for a licence and my DBA said that we don't have a licence because when we purchase a new AS400 system db2 is already included. This is what exactly is logged in console

```
[Error: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1598N  An attempt to connect to the database server failed because of a licensing problem.  SQLSTATE=42968
] {
  error: '[ibm_db] SQL_ERROR',
  sqlcode: -1598,
  state: '42968'
} undefined
```

How I can connect to my on premise db2 instance without purchasing a licence??

Comment: As per advice given in comments as responses to other questions from yourself, this message shows you are using CLIDRIVER  instead of the "IBM i access" odbc driver.  The former requires a licence file, the latter does not.  Configure your ibm_db to use IBM i access instead of CLIDRIVER by removing clidriver and ensuring that the (already installed) IBM i access odbc driver is on the PATH (before any clidriver directories or data-server-client directories) when node runs, and mention the IBM i access driver in the ibm_db.open connection string.

Comment: How I set the IBM i access driver in path and how I will remove the cli driver from the library?Can you post an answer for this please?

Comment: To uninstall clidriver, simply remove its containing directory (in a cmd.exe window, use `pip show ibm_db` to see the path of "Location:" , and "clidriver" directory is in that site-packages directory.

Comment: For the IBM i access odbc driver, we cannot know what's on your pc and how/where it was installed. You really ought to know already how to set persistent environment variables on Microsoft-Windows. Get local help. This is not a matter for stackoverflow.